# Google Analytics for individual visitor

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there any way to track data from google analytics with respect to each visitor per session and then send an email containing this data to the site administrator? Such that data with respect to each visitor is sent as an email. Using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Send e-mail with JavaScript? I bet you cannot.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I think javascript can call to the server, the server can send that mail

Comment: Basically I need help to collect google analytics data using google analytics api with javascript per visitor session. I have the following function:
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
 
    'ids': 'ga:23912',
    'start-date': '2012-11-30',
    'end-date': '2012-12-04',
 'metrics':'ga:timeOnSite,ga:visits,ga:pageviews',
 'segment':'dynamic::ga:customVarValue5==1437834671',
    'dimensions': 'ga:customVarValue5,ga:date,ga:source,ga:pagePath,ga:visitorType',

  }).execute(handleCoreReportingResults);
} how to provide the visitor id per session for ga:customVarValue5?

Comment: Tracking data that identifies a single person is a violation of Googles terms of service (http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) so even if it were possible you'd have to be very careful to anonymize the data.

Comment: Yes the person is fully anonymized but I want to know how this can be achieved using javascript